# Расстановка запятых

Tags: пунктуация

Подскажите, пожалуйста, ставятся ли запятые:
Именно поэтому () такого понятия(,) как "свергнуть" у них не существует.

Comment: Спасибо большое за ответы и объяснение!

Answer (score 1):

Именно поэтому такого понятия, как "свергнуть", у них не существует. Вот так должны быть расставлены запятые в этом предложении

Answer (score 0):

Правильно: Именно поэтому такого понятия, как "свергнуть", у них не существует.

ПОЯСНЕНИЕ

Всегда обособляются обороты с повтором вида ТАК…КАК, ТАКОЙ…КАК, например:

Редко встретишь такого интересного человека, как он. В лесу зимой так красиво, как в сказке. Я никогда не видел леса таким прекрасным, как в эту ночь. И разве так, как теперь, жил Париж!

Для постановки запятой после "именно поэтому" нет оснований, так как это необособленное обстоятельство: частица ИМЕННО + местоименное наречие ПОЭТОМУ